# In VS Code, how to prevent the editor from changing line ending

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code tend to change line ending when I make changes to file, usually from CRLF to LF. how to deactivate this feature? I want VS Code to just leave the line ending as-as

Comment: are your line endings in the file inconsistent / mixed? or are you only using CRLF in that file?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it is not possible. A specific issue has been filed in the GitHub repository of VS Code, but it still open at the moment. You can find all the details here:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/127

Comment: note that next time you can custom-flag your community-deleted answer for undeletion after editing [into shape](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425692/11107541) :)

Answer (score 1):

Having mixed end-of-line types in a single file produces troubles to many programs. Use a single type of end of lines.

For a specific file, there is a indicator that reads either `LF` or `CRLF` on the right side of the application status bar (the bottom bar). Click on it, select the desired type of end-of-line and that should fix the issues with that file.

For all files, search for `files.eol` in the application settings and choose the type of end of line that you prefer.

It's 2023 and most tools and text editors, even on Windows, understand both types of new line endings. Use the Unix conventions (`LF`, `\n`). It is better than the Windows convention (`CRLF`, `\r\n`).